# Local Storage Vs Session Storage Advice needed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, session-cookies, shopping-cart

I am building a mini-swiggy application for selling pizza only with basic functionalities. The basic app is available [here](https://the-pizza-pro.herokuapp.com/). This app doesn't have a login/register feature which I want to add to this app. I want to learn session storage while implementing this.

My question is:

- should I make an API call for every time the user clicks on the add button, and update the cart at the database? (Currently being handled by react context API using local storage, there is no database as such for now. On placing the order I am simply flushing the local storage).
- Now the database is required for features

  - login/register
  - order Summary for each user
  - session management
  - admin roles etc.
- In could just keep using local storage for updating the carts and only make an API call when the user places an order. And I can flush the cart from local storage once the order is placed.(This is I feel is more optimal since it will be better for performance and reduce the server load as well.)

Can all this be achieved without using redux?

Kindly help, considering I want to make it an app with best practices, Also if you have some good resources please share, I am kinda newbie here.

In case you could think of any other features please let me know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to begin with, I want to say I really liked your *CSS* :).

You don't have to use a **database** or **redux** for making a cart system, but as you can guess they have good opportunities.

---

**DATABASE ADVANTAGES**:

1. You can show the user's cart on all his devices.
2. User's cart will be always here as long as he did not delete it.
3. You can reach the data on all components. (hard)
4. It's very good practice for learning.

**DATABASE DISADVANTAGES**:

1. You need an API so, it's hard to set up.
2. Your code will be more complicated than other choices.

---

**REDUX ADVANTAGES**

1. It's kinda easy to set up. You don't need a new project.
2. You can reach the data on all components. (medium)

**REDUX DISADVANTAGES**

1. Actually I really don't know any disadvantages of redux :) (pls tell me if you know)

---

**LOCALSTORAGE ADVANTAGES**

1. Very easy
2. You can reach the data on all components. (easy)

**LOCALSTORAGE DISADVANTAGES**

1. You can't show a user's cart on another device

---

I didn't separate **session storage** because it's the same as **local storage**. The only difference is session storage is **per-tab**.

**In my opinion**, you should use a **database**. I know it's a basic app but you can learn a lot of things by doing it this way.

And these are my recommendations:

1. [cookies vs local vs session storage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GihQAC1I39Q)
2. [ECommerce site with backend](https://youtu.be/TRCDsB9i3bI?list=PLeh2GWv22bmQYQjd5JS8o-GSd4hVkLheW)

Comment: Hey Thanks Buddy, your answer was really insightful, I would proceed with database only as I can see more learning opportunities with robust features. And Since I will be using database I think session storage will be fine only for login sessions. But I feel websites like these generally have infinite session storage value, cause whenever we access the page we generally find ourselves logged in. How should I keep it?

Comment: It's a little different topic but I will try to explain it.  You need to assign a token (you can use long random int :) ) to users while creating their accounts. And save the token to local storage when someone logged in. When the same user opens your website on the same device, get the token from local storage and automatically open users account without any information. [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnXJ-HAcKzE) a better-explained video. And if this answer helped your problem please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should update the database every time the user clicks on the add button, and update the cart at the database.
2. You can use different user authentication methods like using the google sign-in method or you can create a custom user authentication using JWT(JSON Web Token).
3. Having user cart info at local storage until the user places the order wouldn't be a good idea, cart info is critical user data, and you can't update the user cart to all the other devices where the user has logged in, and the cart data will also get vanished once user deletes the browser data, which could be a signification loss to the business.
4. Instead of redux you can use react reducer with react context.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the insights and suggestion I will be taking them. Since I am new to react could you please tell me when to use redux and the react-reducer and react context?

Comment: You can use react-reducer with react-context all the time and in any project, whether it is large or small, using both the ways you can \manage state globally or by using react-reducer and react context you can even co-locate state within a group of the component.  https://www.framelessgrid.com/react-hooks-vs-redux-for-state-management-in-2021/#:~:text=React%20state%20management%3A%20react%20hooks,Redux%3A%20what%20is%20the%20difference%3F&text=The%20main%20difference%20is%20that,state%20container%20within%20your%20component.

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting question, I will answer only one part of it, otherwise it will get too long to read :)

Whether you need to make an API call to persist the cart server-side or just do it only once the order has been placed is a question regarding the business logic of your app itself.

Ask a question, "Do I want my users to be able to add items to the cart and watch/update/edit its' content even if they log in from a different machine/browser?"

If the answer is yes then for sure you have to synchronize your cart with the server so it can be consistent always. For this purpose I would suggest having sort of a queue, which will have the last version of the locally modified cart, once the user did no action for 2000ms to your cart, you can safely make an API call and persist the information of the cart in your DB.

This will reduce the load to your server, because people can increment the number of items you have in the cart by clicking 20 times on the `add` button, in this case, instead of sending 20 requests to the server one at a time, it simply delays the process of persistent the cart, until the user stops interacting with your app for some X amount of milliseconds.

Comment: Actually whatever you said about reducing the load server, I thought of doing it and tried too, but I wasn't successful. I guess its one of the general tech practices, could you suggest me some of the examples where its done? and if its general that what its is called? I thought its somewhat similar to debouncing.

Comment: Yes, you're right, there are mainly 2 concepts, throttling and debouncing in programming. This article has good examples with react, I believe it can help you to implement same concepts in your example also https://medium.com/@kartikag01/debounce-api-request-in-react-functional-component-664b4971d9dd

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [NextAuth](https://next-auth.js.org/) for session management and authentication with combination of [Strapi CMS](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/getting-started/introduction.html) it will be strong and easy for your project.

Comment: Thanks I will explore it, as of now I was thinking to use express-session with flash and mongo-connect for database. Is that not good?

Comment: It is also a good selection but you can try CMS first then go on express or other stacks.